# Query tables by IO stats?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

Is there a MSSQLServer query I can run to show me:

1. Top tables by IO writes overall and for a given time window?
2. Top tables by IO reads overall and for a given time window?

Comment: For a given time period, no. You may be able to make some approximations using `dm_db_index_operational_stats` and `dm_db_index_usage_stats`

Comment: with sql server 2016 or above you can use the query store but the io are divided by query, not by tables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exactly what you asked does not seem to be fully achievable
Alternatively, here is what you can do:

1. Check virtual file IO stats  (reads, writes, GB read, written, average reads, writes, etc.) for each database and log files on a server - since server restart

https://github.com/aleksey-vitsko/Database-Administrator-Tools/blob/master/Storage%20-%20VirtualFileStats.sql

2. Use below query to gather info on table usage (how heavy each table is used - inserts, updates, deletes, row locks, page locks, range locks, lookups) inside given user database - since server restart

```
SELECT 
    s.[name]                            [SchemaName],
    t.[name]                            [TableName],
       
    sum(iop.leaf_insert_count)          [Inserts],
    sum(iop.leaf_delete_count)          [Deletes],
    sum(iop.leaf_update_count)          [Updates],
      
    sum(iop.row_lock_count)             [RowLocks],
    sum(iop.page_lock_count)            [PageLocks],

    sum(iop.row_lock_count) +  sum(iop.page_lock_count)  [Row+Page Locks],

    sum(iop.range_scan_count)           [RangeScans],
    sum(iop.singleton_lookup_count)     [Lookups]
FROM sys.dm_db_index_operational_stats(DB_ID(),NULL,NULL,NULL) AS iop
    JOIN sys.indexes AS i 
        ON iop.index_id = i.index_id 
        AND iop.object_id = i.object_id
    JOIN sys.tables AS t ON 
        i.object_id = t.object_id 
        AND i.type_desc IN ('CLUSTERED', 'HEAP')
    join sys.schemas s on
        t.schema_id = s.schema_id
group by s.[name], t.name
order by [Row+Page Locks] desc
```

**update:**

3. In monitoring tools (Redgate SQL Monitor, Idera, etc.), you can actually select a time window, and view Top Queries for that time window, sorted by IO metrics (Logical Reads, Logical Writes, CPU, etc.). These queries can hint which tables actually been used, and you can do some calculations / approximations from there